# HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request is being displayed on adding @Valid annotation to my controller

Tags: spring-mvc, nhibernate-validator

I'm trying to add a Validation to my form using Hibernate Validator to my project. On submitting the page below is the error message being displayed. But when I remove **@Valid** annotation from my Controller (**UserController.handleLogin**) method I'm able to submit the details. Can someone please suggest what am I missing?

[image: On Submitting Login Form]

> UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {   

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" })
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("command", new LoginCommand());
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleLogin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("err", null);
    return "redirect:index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command") LoginCommand cmd, Model model, HttpSession session, Errors error) {
    if(error.hasErrors()) {
        return "index";
    }
    try {
        User loggedInUser = userService.doLogin(cmd.getLoginName(), cmd.getPassword());
        if (loggedInUser == null) {
            model.addAttribute("err", "Login failed, enter valid credentials");
            return "index";
        } else {

            if (loggedInUser.getRole().equals(UserService.ROLE_ADMIN)) {
                // add user to session
                addUserToSession(loggedInUser, session);
                return "redirect:admin/dashboard";
            } else if (loggedInUser.getRole().equals(UserService.ROLE_USER)) {
                // add user to session
                addUserToSession(loggedInUser, session);
                return "redirect:user/dashboard";
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("err", "Invalid User Role");
                return "index";
            }
        }
    } catch (UserBlockedException e) {
        model.addAttribute("err", e.getMessage());
        return "index";
    }
}
}
```

> LoginCommand.java

```
public class LoginCommand {

    @Size(max = 20, min = 3, message = "Login Name must be between 3 and 20 characters")
    private String loginName;

    @Size(max = 20, min = 3, message = "Password cannot be empty")
    private String password;

    public String getLoginName() {
        return loginName;
    }

    public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
        this.loginName = loginName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

> index.jsp

```
<s:url var="url_login" value="/login"></s:url>
<f:form action="${url_login}" modelAttribute="command" valign="middle" method="POST">
    <table border="1" align="center" width="40%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" valign="middle" align="center">
                    <h2>Login here</h2></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Username: </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <f:input path="loginName" placeholder="Enter your username"/>
                    <f:errors path="loginName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Password: </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <f:password path="password" placeholder="Enter your password"/>
                    <f:errors path="password"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <f:button>Login</f:button>
                    <a href="${url_reg_form}" class="newReg">New User Registration</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</f:form>
```

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how JSR303 validation with Spring is supposed to work. That `@Valid` causes the checks to be made outside of your code and never passed down to it. Spring returns the 400 automatically.

Comment: So how do I make it to pass? Or what changes can be done to make validations work here?

Comment: There are a number of ways to customize the error handling in this case. This blog post of mine shows the way we used and links to a couple of more detailed articles about your options: https://dougbreaux.github.io/2018/05/23/springmvc-jsr303-validation-customization.html

Answer (score 0):

Add Binding result to your method.

BindingResult bindingResult

Comment: I replaced Errors with BindingResult, but I get the same error